# Mean.JS Angular - Returning a single result

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

Im trying to learn Angular.js and have a small problem here. I have created a page that views ALL customers but what im trying to figure out is how to create a page where you just have an individual customer.

On the list all customers page i have

```
data-ng-repeat="customer in customers"
```

which returns all customers but how do i just limit that to an individual result on the view single customer page. The URL is customers/55b4fb75778becf4255b2ea5 so i assume it needs to be something equivalent to WHERE customer.id = "55b4fb75778becf4255b2ea5"

Comment: You should at least go through the [angular-phonecat](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) tutorial before asking, since the question is very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe ur using routes to show details of a particular costumer from a list
try using this within element
{{customers[whichItem].name}}